# Let $A, B \in B(X)$, and $C \in B(Y)$. If $V = \begin{pmatrix}A&0\\ B&C\end{pmatrix}$, how do we define the operator $V|_X$?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory

The problem here is that we have an operator $V \in B(X \oplus Y)$, and it would be straightforward if $V = \begin{pmatrix}A&0\\ 0&C\end{pmatrix}$. Here, it's simple: $V|_X = A$ and $V|_Y = C$.

But if $V = \begin{pmatrix}A&0\\ B&C\end{pmatrix}$, how do we define $V|_X$? Is it $A + B$? Is it something else?

I can't find anything on the internet how we define it in such a situation.

Comment: But then $B$ is a map from $X$ to $Y$, so you’ve misstated it. But, yes, it’s $A\oplus B$ as a map to $X\oplus Y$.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up function restriction with the notion of invariant subspaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $V|_X$ has domain $X$ and codomain $X\oplus Y$. So
$$
(V|_X)x=Ax\oplus Bx.
$$

Note that, properly, it is wrong to say that $V|_X=A$ in your first example. Because $A$ has codomain $X$, while $V|_X$ has codomain $X\oplus Y$. So, properly, $V|_X=A\oplus 0$. What people usually do is to consider the projection $P_X$ onto $X$, and then
$$
P_XV|_X=A
$$
(in both cases).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I also thought that this should be the case to be honest, but what I don't understand is that (for $H := X \oplus Y$) if $V$ is an isometry, then by Wold decomposition, it there should be two subspaces $H_1, H_2 \subset H$ such that $V|_{H_1}$ is a unitary operator and $V|_{H_2}$ is a unitarily equivalent to a unilateral shift. If we take for $V$ the matrix $S$ as defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sz.-Nagy%27s_dilation_theorem, it's pretty obvious that our $C$ must be that unilateral shift. But $A \oplus B$ will never be unitary as it's a column!

Comment: In the Wold decomposition, the subspaces are reducing. Which means that the Wold decomposition writes  $V$ in block-diagonal form.  In your notation $B=0$ always.

Comment: But if we have an operator in the form: $$\begin{pmatrix}T&0&0&0&\ldots \\ D_T&0&0&0&\ldots \\ 0&I&0&0&\ldots \\ 0&0&I&0&\ldots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots &\ldots \end{pmatrix}$$ Then how does the Wold composition look like? We have the unilateral shift operator as we can see, but where is the other operator here? Because it really seems to be $\begin{pmatrix}T\\ D_T\end{pmatrix}$, which can't be the case as it's not unitary (as it's a column).

Comment: Not sure why you expect the Wold decomposition to be "visible". There is significant shuffle of bases in the proof. There is no reason why it has to adjust to your original block matrix.

Comment: I guess I just expected to be the case here in the Sz-Nagy isometric dilation, especially as you "can see" the unilateral shift matrix in that block matrix.

Comment: There are two problems that I see. First, that while you "see" a unilateral shift, it "sits wrongly" with the blocks, i.e. it doesn't have an obvious invariant subspace. More importantly, in the Wold decomposition one chooses things so that the isometry ends up being a unitary on the orthogonal to the subspace where it acts as a shift; that's a consequence of the concrete construction and not something you would usually see at first sight.